# Deploying war file to Jetty in Docker: Error 404 Not found, but contexts are known

Tags: java, docker, servlets, jetty, war

I am going through the Hello World tutorial for Jetty [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_and_Maven_HelloWorld#Building_a_WAR_file)

According to the tutorial, I should be able to access it at :8080/hello-world/hello (hello-world comes from the artifact ID in the pom.xml, and hello comes from the web.xml).  When I try this, I get a HTTP Error 404.

When I try to access the web server at http://172.17.0.2:8080/ (172.17.0.2 is the container's ip address) I get the following information displayed:

```
Error 404 - Not Found.
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:

 - /hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3224f60b{hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT,/hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-4591378293374546697.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:10 as step-one                                                                                                 

COPY ./ /var/www/java/
WORKDIR /var/www/java

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y maven

RUN mvn clean package -X

FROM jetty as step-two

COPY --from=step-one /var/www/java/target/hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/

ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/usr/local/jetty/start.jar", "--create-startd=jmx, stats"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>                                                                                 
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
   version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.example.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Jetty HelloWorld</name>

  <properties>
    <jettyVersion>7.2.0.v20101020</jettyVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>


          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


      <plugin>
        <!-- This plugin is needed for the servlet example -->
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution><goals><goal>java</goal></goals></execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.example.HelloWorld</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

HelloServlet.java:

```
package org.example;                                                                                                        

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {   
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello Servlet</h1>");
        response.getWriter().println("session=" + request.getSession(true).getId());
    }   
}
```

Comment: At first glance, I'm a bit confused that you use the base image `jetty` (without tag, i.e. `latest`), which contains Jetty 9.x, but refer to the documentation of Jetty 7, and use Jetty 7 in your POM. Even if this is not the source of the problem, you should be careful about versions...

Comment: Thank you for brining that to my attention.  The reason I use it without a tag is because that is how they use it in the documentation for the jetty image: https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/jetty

Comment: I think that the reason for this is that Jetty 7 and 8 are too old and in EOL status (https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/previousversions.html). Also note, that the documentation from your post states this fact too and provides the link to up-to-date tutorial with Jetty 9: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html#jetty-helloworld

Comment: That was the problem.  The context paths are different in the newer versions.  I had to go to :8080/hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello to access it.